# apache shiro Implementatation

Tags: apache, shiro

I have knowledge of `spring` `jsf` and `hibernate`. I have integrated them and create my own framework. Now I want to add session management to my framework using Apache Shiro. But I do not have any knowledge of Apache Shiro. Can any one guide me on using Apache Shiro. If any tutorials or eBooks available would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation portion of the site.  The Beginner's Introduction Tutorial is helpful.

[Apache Shiro Documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/documentation.html)

Comment: I have been to that blog, it has a great article on how to use PGP Certificates with Shiro.

Answer (score 0):

I have work with Shiro on a few projects, though none of them have utilised Spring components.

In general I would recommend perusing the [Web App](https://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-SessionManagement) section of the Shiro Documentation.

Also consider these points

- Shiro can allow for session management to be delegated to your Servlet environment
- Shiro can be configured to use Native (memory) session management
- Shiro can be configured to not create persistent sessions, requiring authentication on every request
- If the above config is too excessive for your app, you can also configure "noSession" on specific endpoints eg REST paths